# React Native : overscroll effect in Android with webview

Tags: android, react-native, webview

How to hide the overscroll effect at the top when scrolling on Android with React Native? Here is the code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, WebView } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';


export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.statusBar} />
        <WebView
          source={{uri: 'https://example.com'}}
          renderError={() => alert('Merci de vérifier votre connexion Internet', 'Internet non disponible')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  statusBar: {
    backgroundColor: "#1D3B57",
    height: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  }
});
```

[Result with white effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI8UL.jpg).
Thank you.